# OpenVPN for secure browsing OpenWrt

Tags: openvpn, openwrt

I want to setup a private OpenVPN server which will allow me to surf the web securely at home. Essentially I want all my traffic encrypted and protected from my ISP or hackers snooping. How do I go about doing this on OpenWrt? Or in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you have an OpenVPN provider to connect to?

Comment: If you use a OpenWRT Router at home as a VPN Server you cannot protect yourself from your ISP snooping you. If you want to learn how to setup openvpn you should read the openvpn [howto](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html)